# ANT - PLSQL execution error

Tags: oracle, plsql, ant

I have a bunch of sql scripts (some sql and some plsql) to be executed using ant .
Before I start the execution, I need to make sure that the files are executable. So I run the following target to create sql and plsql executable from ant.

```
    <copy todir="${migration.scripts.dir}\temp\">
      <fileset dir="${migration.scripts.dir}" includes="*.sql"/>
      <filterchain>
        <replaceregex byline="false" pattern=";" replace="${line.separator}/" flags="mg"/>
        <replaceregex byline="false" pattern="/[\s]*/" replace=";${line.separator}/"  flags="mg"/>
       </filterchain>
    </copy>
```

And the PLSQL in the file a file is something like this -

```
   BEGIN 
     FOR c IN 
     --query
     LOOP 
       dbms_utility.blah ; 
     END LOOP; 
     COMMIT;
    END;
    /
```

that when ant target makeExecutableSQLs runs outputs -

```
BEGIN 
 FOR c IN 
 --query 
 LOOP 
   dbms_utility.blah 
/ 
 END LOOP
/ 
 COMMIT
/
END
;
/
```

but this when running later fails due to this error -

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>       BEGIN 
>        FOR c IN 
>         --query 
>        LOOP 
>         dbms_utility.blah
>       Error report -
>       ORA-06550: line 9, column 135:
>       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ```
>    := . ( % ;
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:
>
> Error starting at line : 11 in command -
> END LOOP
> Error report -
> Unknown Command
>
>
> Commit complete.
>
>
> Error starting at line : 15 in command -
> END
> Error report -
> Unknown Command
>
>
> Error starting at line : 16 in command -
>
> Error report -
> Unknown Command
> ```

Cant put a finger on where the error is?

Comment: Are you asking why you get the PL/SQL errors, or why `pattern=";" replace="${line.separator}/"` is corrupting the PL/SQL (andthus causing those errors)?

Comment: I know that the replace="${line.separator}/" is causing the "enhanced" script to error out.But for SQL is work well. But for now I want to know why this PLSQL errors is thrown.

Comment: The PL/SQL language uses `;` for a command terminator, not `/` which is the division operator. Obviously the challenge is going to be stopping your Ant script messing up your PL/SQL by injecting invalid characters into it. I don't know Ant though so maybe that's going to be really hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PL/SQL errors are thrown because you have replaced semicolon PL/SQL statement separators with block terminators.

When the compiler sees the `/` it terminates and executes the command in the buffer, so it sees and tries to compile and run

```
BEGIN 
 FOR c IN 
 --query 
 LOOP 
   dbms_utility.blah 
/
```

as a standalone complete PL/SQL block. As the error you get from that

> ORA-06550: line 9, column 135: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" ...

indicates that apparently-complete block ends before it is supposed to. There is no semicolon statement terminator after `blah`, but also no `end loop` or `end` for the block - in that code it is trying to execute. It hasn't seen the rest of the script, effectively.

It then carries on and tries to interpret the next chunk

```
 END LOOP
/
```

which is also invalid; the client doesn't even try to execute that because it doesn't know what to do with it.

Then the next chunk

```
 COMMIT
/
```

is successfully run as a plain SQL (transaction control) statement, not in a PL/SQL context.

And so on.

In short, you cannot replace semicolons with slashes within a PL/SQL block as they do very different things. In plain SQL they are interchangeable (or rather, to most clients they are; at least by default - even in SQL*Plus you can change the SQL terminator from a semicolon to something else).

The client still handles the slash after a PL/SQL block, and when it sees that it sends the block to the DB to be executed. But while it knows it is *inside* a block it knows any semicolons it sees are part of the PL/SQL language and it shouldn't try to interpret them.

This is referred to [in the SQL*Plus documentation for running PL/SQL blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref291), and other clients tend to behave in similar ways.

> Execute the current subprogram with a `RUN` or slash (`/`) command. A semicolon (`;`) is treated as part of the PL/SQL subprogram and will not execute the command.

Comment: This helps, I need to make sure the plsql block stays as is when ant runs through it.